# About proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem

Tags: real-analysis

I was reading the proof of the Bolzano-Weierstrass theorem. I understand that the idea is that if a sequence is bounded by $[a_0,b_0]$, we divide the interval into halves, choose the one with infinitely many points, and choose a point $s_{i_1}$ from the new interval. We repeat the procedure and show that the subsequence $(s_{i_n})$ is convergent.

However, I don't feel comfortable with the "infinity" of this algorithm. Why can we repeat a procedure $\textit{infinitely}$ many times and have a nested interval
$$
[a_0,b_0]\supset [a_1,b_1]\supset \cdots
$$
$[a_n,b_n]$ has length $\frac{b_0-a_0}{2^n}$?

I am also not very comfortable at building a sequence by choosing one element at a time. I am probably too used to finite stuff and manually do things (not mathematically mature enough)...

Comment: If you couldn't repeat his procedure infinitely many times, that would imply at some point you have interval [a,b] that contains infinitely many points of the sequence, but when "splitting that interval in half" around a point in the set $s$, neither $[a,s]$ or $[s,b]$ contain infinitely many points, this would imply that $[a,s]\cup [s,b]=[a,b]$ contains finitely many points, a contradiction.

Comment: You just need a recipe for one more step with the proviso that the next step is well defined. For example, at the $n$th step you have an interval $[a_n,b_n]$. Since this has length $>0$ you can divide it into two equal sized sub intervals (both whose length is $>0$), choose the interval of interest and continue. Then you can continue the recipe a countable number of times.

Comment: "Infinitely many times" is just a placeholder for "you can do it one more time". That is, let's say you've done the bisection $n$ times, then, surely, you can bisect again, so it is always possible to do it $n+1$ times for any $n$. So, in a similar fashion to induction, if for some $k$ we have that $a_k$ is defined and that this implies that $a_{k+1}$ is definable too, then $a_n$ is definable for all $n \geq k$.

Comment: If you are not comfortable with "infinity" then you may not be comfortable with "sequence", to begin with.

Comment: Thank you all!!

Comment: You are exactly right @Mirko I just read my proof again and became comfortable with it.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know if I understood correctly, but your doubt is about the intersection of the intervals
$$
    [a_0, b_0]\subset[a_1, b_1]⊂\cdots
$$
to be an interval?! If it's, then the answer for your doubt is the Nested Interval Theorem. An intuitive approach is that we expect the real line to don't have holes. So, no matter how much you zoom in it, you still will find infinitely many points of the real line, never a hole. The Nested Interval Theorem is the formalization of this idea.